# php 5.6 with cakephp3 syntax error with splat operator

Tags: php, cakephp

I am setting up a new project in cakephp version 3.4. My webserver is a ubuntu 14.04 with PHP5:

```
# php -v
PHP 5.6.30-12~ubuntu14.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli)
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
```

My problem is, that I receive following error when calling my app:

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting '&' or variable (T_VARIABLE) in ~/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/I18n/functions.php on line 26
```

Looks like php is not accepting the new splat operator that came out in php 5.6 (https://lornajane.net/posts/2014/php-5-6-and-the-splat-operator)

Any idea how to fix? I don't even know how to google this problem (except for upgrading to php7, but that's not a solution right now).

Comment: I cannot see any splat operator in your question. Where is the code?

Comment: It's not a problem with the code, it was a problem with my php version running on my apache. See answer below.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Problem solved.

The php version on my ubuntu 14.04 was actually 5.6.30, but the apache version was still 5.5.9.

Fixed it with following commands:

```
sudo a2dismod php5
sudo a2enmod php5.6
sudo service apache2 restart
```